# Как из активности вынести запрос retrofit в отдельный класс

Tags: android, retrofit2, android-room

Есть несколько запросов которые надо выполнять последовательно, хочу вынести из активити все запросы в отдельные классы и вызывать их когда надо по отдельности и хотелось бы использовать хранилище room, но пока что не понимаю как это сделать

```
public class NetworkService {
    private static NetworkService mInstance;
    private static final String BASE_URL = ".....";
    private Retrofit mRetrofit;

    protected NetworkService() {
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .addInterceptor(interceptor);

        mRetrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(client.build())
                .build();
    }

    public static NetworkService getInstance() {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new NetworkService();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public JSONPlaceHolderApi getJSONApi() {
        return mRetrofit.create(JSONPlaceHolderApi.class);
    }

}
```

public void UserInfo (){

```
String androidID = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
Log.d(TAG,savedText);
Log.d(TAG,androidID);

    NetworkService.getInstance()
            .getJSONApi()
            .getUserInfo(new UserInfo(savedText,androidID))
        .enqueue(new Callback<Example>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Example> call, @NonNull Response<Example> response) {

        Example example = response.body();

        switch (response.code()) {
            case 401: {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ваша сессия устарела", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

            case 200:{
                String FirstName = example.firstName;
                save(FirstName,SAVED_First);
                String SurName = example.surName;
                save(SurName,SAVED_Sur);
                String SecondName = example.secondName;
                save(SecondName,SAVED_Second);

                int num = example.contractData.size();
                String [] contract = new String[num];
                String [] contractDate = new String[num];

                for (int i=0;i<num;i++) {
                    contract [i] = example.contractData.get(i).contract;
                    contractDate [i] = example.contractData.get(i).contractDate;

                }

                String Contract = contract[0];
                save(Contract,SAVED_Contract);
                String СontractDate = contractDate[0];
                save(СontractDate,SAVED_ContractDate);

                MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

                mainActivity.FirstName(FirstName);
                mainActivity.SurName(SurName);
                mainActivity.SecondName(SecondName);
                mainActivity.Contract(Contract);
                mainActivity.СontractDate(СontractDate);





            }
            break;
        }

    }

    private  void save(String data1,String data) {
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(data,data1);
        ed.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Example> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
    }
});


}
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что именно вызывает проблемы? Вопрос очень широко поставлен. Возможно, просто опишите свои мысли на этот счет на данный момент.

Comment: выше предоставил код, у меня есть класс где подключается ретрофит и снизу код описывающий запрос этот кусок кода находится в активити я его хочу вынести в другой класс и вызывать только класс в активити когда это нужно, еще проблема с данными щас использую SharedPreferences, но хочу использовать room для подключении LiveData

Answer (score 1, accepted):

То что вы хотите сделать, делается при помощи класса под названием [синглтон](https://habr.com/ru/post/27108/). Суть будет такой - в нужный вам момент из активности вызывается этот класс, и его метод который например шлет запрос. Дальше в этом методе вы сохраняете все в `room` или `SharedPreferences`. [Вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/129494/) пример создания синглтона:

```
public class Singleton {
        private static volatile Singleton instance;

        public static Singleton getInstance() {
        Singleton localInstance = instance;
        if (localInstance == null) {
            synchronized (Singleton.class) {
                localInstance = instance;
                if (localInstance == null) {
                    instance = localInstance = new Singleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return localInstance;
    }
}
```

дальше в этом классе вы создаете метод который будет давать вам доступ к апи из любой активности или фрагмента. У вас этот код находится в классе `NetworkService` но его можно поместить в один класс, синглтона чтобы не плодить кучу классов. Дальше вы в синглтон добавляете метод получения вашего юзер инфо, и сохраняете нужные данные в бд или настройки приложения. И в итоге вы сможете вызвать метод откуда угодно. Но следует помнить, что при создании метода `public void UserInfo (){}` в синглтоне, вам нужно будет сохранять данные в памяти телефона, поэтому стоит передавать в этот метод context чтобы был доступ к SharedPreference. Так же метод:

```
private  void save(String data1,String data) {
        sPref = getSharedPreferences("MyPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed = sPref.edit();
        ed.putString(data,data1);
        ed.commit();
    }
```

можно вынести в синглтон чтобы не засорять активность.

Comment: а при переходе к архитектуре MVVM от синглтонов приходиться отказаться и все что выполнялось в синглтоне переносится в репозиторий я правильно понимаю ?

Comment: @LEON, насколько я знаю можно использовать синглтон и в указанной архитектуре, но без использования ViewModel, но я могу ошибаться :)